# Uninstall linux from Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I'm wondering how to uninstall linux from powershell since it's getting on my nerves that everytime I try to update I get the subsystem linux update when I installed it through powershell. Can anyone help on removing it?

Command I used on Powershell (administrator)

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://wsldownload.azureedge.net/Ubuntu_1604.2019.523.0_x64.appx -OutFile Ubuntu.appx -UseBasicParsing
```

Now I'd like to uninstall this, maybe used a different command but I definitely used something like it

Comment: Keep in mind that questions on this site should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Non-programming WSL questions like yours are typically better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com).  That said, before reposting on Super User, please check out [this question on reinstalling WSL](https://superuser.com/q/1619233/1210833), where my answer covers the uninstall process.  I'll double-check it to make sure it is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed linux distribution with WSL, it gives you ability to manage your distribution.

Run `wsl --list` to find your distribution name.
After that run `wsl --unregister <DistributionName>` to uninstall your distribution.

This link has description on this commands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#unregister-and-reinstall-a-distribution

Comment: That explains how to unregister a distribution, but not how to uninstall WSL.